ipp printer does not print on linux (good on windows)
The Problem:

I cannot print anything with my ipp printer on linux, including test page.
I didn't find anything obviously wrong in Ubuntu Settings.
When I tried to print something, I could see that something entered queue (in Ubuntu Settings) and quickly disappeared, and the printer did not have any response.
The printer itself is fine, because on Windows (virtual machine on same host), it prints without problems.

Printer:
pstat -t
device for HP-LaserJet-Tank-MFP-260x: ipp://10.0.1.201
device for HP_LaserJet_Tank_MFP_2606sdw_AD0294: implicitclass://HP_LaserJet_Tank_MFP_2606sdw_AD0294/


The ipp one is manually added; and the other one is auto scanned in settings. They are the same device.
Software version:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
cups: 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.10

BTW:
Why does Ubuntu Settings ask for manual selection of printer model?
Windows automatically picks the printer model.

Have you followed HP's directions: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/step4/cups/net?
